# How to make property of a layout final?

Tags: android, layout

I am using a layout in my android app. I want to make sure that some property like height is not overridden programtically and the value of property defined in xml takes preference.

Is there a way in android to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with system `View`s,

You can, however, do this with a custom `View`: extend some `View` class (e.g. `TextView`) override the setters you want to disable in code, and simply return in all of them.